# Selcting the first <content> element with polymer 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am using Polymer 1 for web-development and I am encountering a small lack of understanding. Imagine the following:

```
<div class="value">
  <content></content>
</div>
```

I can easily style the content with the `.value` selector. Now I only want to style the First content element. `:first-child` etc. doesn't seem to work.

How can I select different elements of my `<content></content>` in Polymer?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not really use Polymer 1, but the deprecated `content`  tag should be similar to what the `slot` tag is in newer versions.. that being said, it should be just a point where content is inserted, a placeholder, not an actual tag.. so when your page is rendered it won't exist, the content you inject inside will..

Comment: Yes you are right. But that doesn't really help me. The content itself is just another Polymer component, so I can't select it via CSS. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

*Note that [`<content>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content) has been deprecated for [`<slot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot).*

---

To target the first child of the `<slot>`/`<content>`, use [`::slotted(:first-child)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted):

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      foo: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Hello world!'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.8.0/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo>
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
    <div>third</div>
  </x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        ::slotted(:first-child) {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```